# calc.exe file is not getting killed through batch file

Tags: batch-file

I prepared one batch file to open calc.exe as a practice. I deleted the batch file accidentally. Now whenever I am closing the calc.exe application, every time it gets open after 10 seconds. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Process Explorer to see what process calc.exe was started by and prevent that for example by deleting its autorun.

Answer (score 1):

in Task manager, kill the process conhost.exe (more details) or Windows command processor(fewer details) wherever you encounter it.

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Did you purposely start calculator 10 sec after it's been terminated in batch script? But doesn't seems like your deleted batch script is still running. Open cmd and type in `taskkill /im "calc.exe"`, it should taskkill calculator, if it's not, comment below.

Comment: I was doing to learn batch file processing. Agreed it might be still running. I tried to run  taskkill/im "calc.exe". It did kill the process. But after sometime, again calc.exe started.